# javascript posting data to php file

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to insert a base64 image string into my database, Iv'e been messing around with this for a few hours now, tried various different methods and for some reason I can't seem to get it to post the data to my php script.

app.js

```
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert("Please provide signature first.");
    } else {
         var basevalue = signaturePad.toDataURL();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: { basevle: basevalue }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });

    }
});
```

insert.php

```
basevalue = $_POST['basevle']; 

try {
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO signatures VALUES (0,:sigbase)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':sigbase', $signature);

    $signature = $basevalue);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "added";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the php file as Iv'e tested it and it's inserting values, it seems to be the app.js not sending the post data

Anyone got any thoughts on what could be causing the issue ?

Comment: have you tried debugging? what prints var_dump($_POST['basevle']); for exemple? Are you sure the data is sent? Did you check your browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible that this PHP file is working.

First of all, you must declare your `baseValue` variable with a `$` prefixing it.

Second, you're using a `$signature` variable before even declaring it. You're declaring it and passing the `$baseValue` value to it **after** using it, what is never gonna work.

You must put the line `$signature = $baseValue;` before calling the `bindParam` method.

Comment: Iv'e actually added the $ before the basevalue but it got cut off when I copied and pasted the snippet, as for moving the $signature = $basevalue it makes no difference which way around it is, checked using $_GET and it works both ways